# How to call api once in futurebuilder

Tags: flutter, bloc

My application have different routes and I would like to know how to call my api with cubit just once when the user come for the first time on the screen and also not to re-call the api every time he returns to the screen already initialized.

my structure use bloC

and this is my profile page initialization class

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
final theme = Theme.of(context);
final user = context.read<AuthCubit>().state;
final bloc = context.read<ProfileCubit>();

return Scaffold(
  body: FutureBuilder(
    future: bloc.updateProfilePicture(user!.id),
    builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
      if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
        return BlocBuilder<ProfileCubit, ProfilePicture?>(
          buildWhen: (prev, curr) => prev != curr,
          builder: (context, picture) {
            return picture != null
                ? Profil(profilePicture: picture, updateIndex: updateIndex)
                : Profil(updateIndex: updateIndex);
          },
        );
      }
      return Center(
        child: CircularProgressIndicator(
          color: Colors.orange,
        ),
      );
    },
  ),
);
}
```

Comment: you can have some idea [here](https://flutter-examples.com/futurebuilder-is-called-multiple-times/).

Answer (score 0):

This solution helped me a lot.

```
class StatefulWrapper extends StatefulWidget { final Function onInit; final Widget child; final Function? onReload; const StatefulWrapper({super.key, required this.onInit, required this.child, this.onReload}); @override _StatefulWrapperState createState() => _StatefulWrapperState(); } class _StatefulWrapperState extends State<StatefulWrapper> { @override void initState() { widget.onInit(); super.initState(); } @override Widget build(BuildContext context) { if (widget.onReload != null) widget.onReload!(); return widget.child; } }
```

Answer (score -1):

There are many ways to solve this problem
1- easy (but not clean code) is to use boolean global varibal
like isApiReqursted with default value (false) and when call the api set it to true
2- you can cache the response in the repoistory or bloc and make the api method frst check if there are data if there isit does not need to make http request